# postgres function that takes the result of a select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a postgres function that takes the result of a select. The detail that requires this use-case is that I'm within the context of a statement-level trigger, so I have the `NEW` and `OLD` pseudo-tables, and I'd like to call a function with them as the argument.

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trg
AFTER INSERT ON my_table
REFERENCING
    NEW TABLE AS my_inserted_records
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger_func();
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_trigger_func()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN

    SELECT the_other_func(
        (SELECT * FROM my_inserted_records)
    );

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION the_other_func(
   ...what here???...
)
RETURNS JSONB
AS $$
    -- do something
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

I want to be able to call `the_other_func` from a similar `UPDATE` trigger, which also contains the pseudo-tables.

Is this possible? Thanks! (I'm using postgres 14)

Comment: I think you should also post what data you currently have and what you want to achieve? Someone else might give you better solution than you are trying to implement.

Comment: Whats the point? You won't  be able to return the output of the `the_other_func()`. Just do what you need with `my_inserted_records` inside the trigger function.

Comment: Replace the * with the column names you select and you now know exactly what the input will be for your function. But it's not clear what you try to achieve and if you need this to accomplish your unknown target.

Comment: you can't get there from here,  function arguments must be single vlaues, not result-sets or tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't get there from here,  function arguments must be single values, including record types and arrays, but not result-sets or tables.

look for a way to have the `the_other_func` be a trigger function
perhaps using arguments customize its operation for different tables. that will probably be a cleaner solution than the following

As arrays are allowed perhaps you could try an array of records.

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_trigger_func()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN

    PERFORM the_other_func (array_agg(i)) 
       FROM my_inserted_records AS i ;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

with the otherfunc being defined as.

```
CREATE FUNCTION the_other_func(
   newdata my_table[]
)
...
```

Comment: I wound up creating a new `TYPE`, using an array of the new type as the argument to `the_other_func`, and using array_agg from the function, selecting the required columns for `the_other_func`. I had tried the `my_table[]`, but got runtime errors like `the_other_func(record[])` does not exist. I'm not thrilled with the result, but it's working! Thanks for your help!

Comment: yeah, this is not a good solution, which is why i sugested looking for other ways to do whaterver it is you need to do. I think arrays are O(n^2) which may be problematic.

Comment: perhaps you can use an aggregate function instead?